# Getting error while install mod_wsgi on centos6.3 with python 2.7

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, mod-wsgi

In initially installed `yum install mod_wsgi` and i think it was linked with python 2.6

Now is there any way to link it with 2.7

I tried configuring from the source and i get this error

```
apxs -c -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config  -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
In file included from /usr/local/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                 from mod_wsgi.c:142:
/usr/local/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1161:1: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/apr-1/apr-x86_64.h:127,
                 from /usr/include/apr-1/apr.h:19,
                 from /usr/include/httpd/ap_config.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/httpd/httpd.h:43,
                 from mod_wsgi.c:34:
/usr/include/features.h:162:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/local/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                 from mod_wsgi.c:142:
/usr/local/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1183:1: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/apr-1/apr-x86_64.h:127,
                 from /usr/include/apr-1/apr.h:19,
                 from /usr/include/httpd/ap_config.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/httpd/httpd.h:43,
                 from mod_wsgi.c:34:
/usr/include/features.h:164:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_server_group’:
mod_wsgi.c:991: warning: unused variable ‘value’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘Log_isatty’:
mod_wsgi.c:1665: warning: unused variable ‘result’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘Log_writelines’:
mod_wsgi.c:1802: warning: unused variable ‘msg’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘Adapter_output’:
mod_wsgi.c:3087: warning: unused variable ‘n’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘Adapter_file_wrapper’:
mod_wsgi.c:4138: warning: unused variable ‘result’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_python_term’:
mod_wsgi.c:5850: warning: unused variable ‘tstate’
mod_wsgi.c:5849: warning: unused variable ‘interp’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_python_child_init’:
mod_wsgi.c:7050: warning: unused variable ‘l’
mod_wsgi.c:6948: warning: unused variable ‘interp’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_add_import_script’:
mod_wsgi.c:7701: warning: unused variable ‘error’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_add_handler_script’:
mod_wsgi.c:8179: warning: unused variable ‘dconfig’
mod_wsgi.c:8178: warning: unused variable ‘sconfig’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_hook_handler’:
mod_wsgi.c:9375: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:9377: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:9379: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:9383: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:9403: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:9405: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:9408: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_daemon_worker’:
mod_wsgi.c:10819: warning: unused variable ‘duration’
mod_wsgi.c:10818: warning: unused variable ‘start’
mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_hook_daemon_handler’:
mod_wsgi.c:13172: warning: unused variable ‘i’
mod_wsgi.c:13170: warning: unused variable ‘elts’
mod_wsgi.c:13169: warning: unused variable ‘head’
mod_wsgi.c: At top level:
mod_wsgi.c:8142: warning: ‘wsgi_set_user_authoritative’ defined but not used
mod_wsgi.c:15251: warning: ‘wsgi_hook_check_user_id’ defined but not used
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/lib64/httpd/modules -module -avoid-version    mod_wsgi.lo -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

Waiting for Graham

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the mod_wsgi documentation.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Mixing_32_Bit_And_64_Bit_Packages

Do what you are told to do in the documentation.